# Mongo large chunks will not split

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I had a 3 shard set up, and ran out of capacity, so I added 3 more shards. (Each shard is a replica set).  But the data isn't spread across the cluster evenly.  I have my chunkSize set to the stock 64:

```
mongos> db.settings.find( { _id:"chunksize" } )
{ "_id" : "chunksize", "value" : 64 }
```

I thought this meant that when a chunk hits 64mb, it splits into two equal chunks both of size 32mb.  That's what is demonstrated [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/sharding-chunk-splitting/).  Is that not correct?

Here is my sharding distribution:

```
mongos> db.accounts.getShardDistribution()
Shard rs_0 at rs_0/mongo_rs_0_member_1:27018,mongo_rs_0_member_2:27019,mongo_rs_0_member_3:27020
 data : 137.62GiB docs : 41991598 chunks : 1882
 estimated data per chunk : 74.88MiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 22312

Shard rs_1 at rs_1/mongo_rs_1_member_1:27018,mongo_rs_1_member_2:27019,mongo_rs_1_member_3:27020
 data : 135.2GiB docs : 41159069 chunks : 1882
 estimated data per chunk : 73.56MiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 21869

Shard rs_2 at rs_2/mongo_rs_2_member_1:27018,mongo_rs_2_member_2:27019,mongo_rs_2_member_3:27020
 data : 219.92GiB docs : 69739096 chunks : 1882
 estimated data per chunk : 119.66MiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 37055

Shard rs_3 at rs_3/mongo_rs_3_member_1:27018,mongo_rs_3_member_2:27019,mongo_rs_3_member_3:27020
 data : 101.52GiB docs : 30650628 chunks : 1882
 estimated data per chunk : 55.23MiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 16286

Shard rs_4 at rs_4/mongo_rs_4_member_1:27018,mongo_rs_4_member_2:27019,mongo_rs_4_member_3:27020
 data : 103.38GiB docs : 31071379 chunks : 1883
 estimated data per chunk : 56.22MiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 16500

Shard rs_5 at rs_5/mongo_rs_5_member_1:27018,mongo_rs_5_member_2:27019,mongo_rs_5_member_3:27020
 data : 101.1GiB docs : 30516395 chunks : 1881
 estimated data per chunk : 55.04MiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 16223

Totals
 data : 798.77GiB docs : 245128165 chunks : 11292
 Shard rs_0 contains 17.23% data, 17.13% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 3KiB
 Shard rs_1 contains 16.92% data, 16.79% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 3KiB
 Shard rs_2 contains 27.53% data, 28.45% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 3KiB
 Shard rs_3 contains 12.7% data, 12.5% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 3KiB
 Shard rs_4 contains 12.94% data, 12.67% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 3KiB
 Shard rs_5 contains 12.65% data, 12.44% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 3KiB
```

What's up with this? How can the first 3 shards/replica sets have an average size greater than 64mb when that is set to be chunkSize? Rs_2 is 119mb!  Rs_2 has 27.53% of the data when it should have 16.6%.

What should I do here? I can manually find chunks that are large and split them, but that is a pain.  Do I lower my chunkSize? Is there some service/call I need to run to do this automatically?

Comment: Normally chunks become too large before splitting due to a bad shard key that allows this to happen

Comment: What is your shard key?

Comment: it's a user's cookie, the cardinality of it is over 10 million, or somewhere there abouts

Comment: We can't answer too much since this is really a DBA question (hence we have voted to close and move your question over there) however what data is stored to this key? So basically I assume you are probably storing session data in there right? Can a session get quite big? Do you ever reinsert shard key rows? etc etc

Comment: Probably on rs_2 you have some chunk marked as jumbo, and this chunk will be not splited, please read mongo docs how to find jumbo chunk and how to remove jumbo flag from chunk,

You have different data distribution, because mongo migrate chunks across cluster based on chunk number not based on data size, that you have equal number of chunk per node.